# Textbox format into Datetime?

Tags: vb.net

I had a problem manipulating the textbox. This is the date format `2019-10-10 05-21-27` and I was about to convert it using datetime. But it seems it cannot be Format like this `2019-10-10 05:21:27` I tried several codes for this one but it did not work.
Here is my code:

```
Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact(tbox_dateofS.Text, "d/M", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            tbox_dateofS.Text = d.ToString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss")
```

i tried this one also:

```
 tbox_dateofS.Text = Cdate(node.SelectSingleNode("starttime").InnerText).Tostring("yyyy-mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
```

And I got this error : `System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'`

Comment: Which date format would you like to get?

Comment: `2019-10-10 05:21:27` or "YYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Formatting date with this kind of string `2019-10-10 05-21-27` was very hard for me because the time is using "dash" not "colon"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

05-21-27 **is a bad format (WITH FORMAT STYLE "d/M")** to convert in a time object.
So if you don’t want to change your INPUT format use the method below as a workaround otherwise in order to have a correct date Object you need to change your time input string in 05:21:27 and after to format this date in your style again as you want.

```
Private Function getFormatedDate(sDate As String, Optional formatString As String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

    Dim correctDateString As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To sDate.Length - 1
        If IsNumeric(CChar(sDate(i))) OrElse sDate(i) = " " Then
            correctDateString &= sDate(i)
        Else
            If i < 10 Then
                correctDateString &= "/"
            Else
                correctDateString &= ":"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return Strings.Format(CDate(correctDateString), formatString)

End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim mCorrectDateString As String = getFormatedDate("2019-10-10 05-21-27")
```

Comment: Let me to add something else: If your input format is always the same as yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss the @jmcilhinney  method is more efficient and clear code.

Comment: I think this is sort of string manipulation. But it fix everything in my code

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be formatted like that.  You simply need to specify the correct format to convert FROM in order to get a `Date` that you can then format however you want.

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim text = "2019-10-10 05-21-27"
        Dim dt As Date

        If Date.TryParseExact(text, "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss", Nothing, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

It works exactly as you should expect.

That said, why use a `TextBox` in the first place?  In most cases, you can use a `DateTimePicker` and it will handle all the formatting and validation for you.

Comment: I gave you -1 involuntarily.
Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, I think that you can just click the up arrow to give an up vote instead of down but not sure that you can just remove a vote. Never looked into it. No big deal though. Just send chocolate to make up for it.

Comment: I tried before the first comment but obviously doesn’t work.
The chocolate is for girls. If I’m not wrong, how about a Brunello di Montalcino  or Morellino di Scansano or a good Chianti? :P